# Is better to create the zip archetype with maven assembly plugin as of project.basedir or project.build.directory?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am working on a project and I have to generate a zip archetype. Inside the src directory there is a component.json file which I need to copy into the target directory and put it inside the .zip archetype as well. But before copying it, some values inside this file need to be updated, and this should happen every time I build the project.

The reason we update the component.json file is because we want to set the right version and image tag of the component, so people who is going to use the component will know with version and image tag they are using.

Currently the file that I am using to generate the .zip archetype is under src directory.

There are some problems with this current approach.

1.- Every time I build the project git marks it like a change to be committed. I want to avoid this.

2.- I am using maven-resources-plugin to copy the component.json file into the project.build.directory. At this point, my thinking is, once the component.json file is copied in the project.build.directory, update this file instead of the one is under src and generate the .zip archetype as of this file.

3.- Regarding to point 2, another doubt comes to my mind, I don't know how maven works internally about which step or plugin is going to be executed first, the one which copies the file into the project.build.directory or the one which generates the .zip archetype.

So, basically I want to hear your thoughts about what's the best approach to handle this and your previous experience with a similar situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most important point: Never let Maven generate anything *outside* the `target` directory. It causes all kinds of problems with Git and maintaining a clean project.

The Maven build follows the Maven [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Here, you can see the order of the different phases and can pick the right phase for your manipulation.

Comment: Thanks JF for sharing the link, very useful information. So, do you agree with me in point 2?

Comment: Yes, this is what you need to do.